# Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have such pretty simple **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine

ADD ./service /

RUN chmod +x /service

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["./service"]
```

With this Dockerfile I successfully created image but I have error when try to create container.

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

This error can happens when something wrong with binary file or with OS/ARCH of docker container.

`service` is a binary file of Golang application. In my case Golang application use CGO packages. I compile it in my local machine which is Windows 10. Here is my instruction:

- Install [tdm-gcc](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download). A compiler suite for 32- and 64-bit Windows based on the GNU toolchain.
- In `POWERSHELL` execute commands:

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
go build -v -o questionnaire -ldflags="-extld=$CC"
```

`go env` command return me next:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\NNogerbek\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\NNogerbek\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\NNOGER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build371579938=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Where I make mistake and how to fix this problem?

---

I also tried to compile binary inside docker with such Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.11

WORKDIR /go/src/application
ADD . .


RUN go get ./...
RUN go build -o /service .

ENV PORT=8000

CMD ["/service"]
```

I don't know why but I have error. Somehow Docker can't import project packages:

```
package application/database: unrecognized import path "application/database" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package application/routes: unrecognized import path "application/routes" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package application/utils: unrecognized import path "application/utils" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package application/models: unrecognized import path "application/models" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package application/controllers: unrecognized import path "application/controllers" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

By the way project structure:

```
- application
    - database
    - routes
    - utils
    - models
    - controllers
      main.go
      Dockerfile
```

Comment: Have already told you `permission denied`, try to run it as  `sudo docker`

Comment: @FrankAK I use `sude`. For example I tried to create container like that: `sudo docker run --name application_container -d -p 8000:8000 application_image`. I also used `sudo chmod 775 service` command for binary file. The error message was the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: @FrankAK as you can see in the top of the Dockerfile I set `FROM golang:1.11`. As I know it is `Debian`. Maybe in Debian I start binary file incorrectly (`ENTRYPOINT` part of Dockerfile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand that compile `linux/amd64` binary file of `Goland` application which use `CGO` packages in Windows OS is not good idea. Binary file which I tried to start in Docker container always raised error `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"`. Error mean that something wrong with `OS/Arch` or you use corrupted file.

Finally I decided to compile binary file inside Docker container. My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.11

WORKDIR /go/src/application

ADD . .

RUN go get [your_dependencies]

RUN go build -o service

ENV PORT=8000

CMD ["./service"]
```

I hope this post will be useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

What is `SRC_DIR` value and moreover does `./service` has executable permissions.
Try to run `chmod +x ./service` on host machine or in `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Hello! I already did that. Can you check my post again please? I tried a lot of things to run my Golang application in Docker. But in every variant I have problems. Do you have any ideas?